# Trazer a contagem da palavra "DADOS" de uma coluna calculada no SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Bom dia, tenho uma consulta que traz em uma coluna calculada as informações de "Dados" e "Historicos", nesta coluna eu tenho o Prefixo do item (placa do veiculo) e a coluna com o respectivo cálculo.
Eu preciso alterar esta consulta de modo que me traga as informações de Prefixo e a contagem de quantas palavras "Dados" apareceram para este Item.
 Abaixo segue a consulta que eu estou utilizado como base para tentar desenvolver isso:

```
 SELECT
     [CAM_CD] as COD
    ,[CAM_PF] As CAM
    ,[CAM_DS_PLACA] as PLACA
    ,[CAM_CR_LATITUDE] as LATITUDE
    ,[CAM_CR_LONGITUDE] as LONGITUDE
    ,[CAM_DT_REGISTRO] as DT_REGISTRO
    ,convert(char(8), [CAM_DT_REGISTRO], 108) as 'HoraA'
    ,DATEPART(Hour, [CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) as 'HoraB'   
    ,DATEPART(DD,[CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) as 'Dia'
    ,DATEPART(MM,[CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) as 'Mes'
    ,DATEPART(YY,[CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) as 'Ano'   
    ,[CAM_DT_BD]
    --Coluna que deve ser contada na nova query
     ,case when 
            ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_CD] asc)) OR
            ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],2)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_CD] asc))                                
           then 'Historico' else 'Dados' 
    end as [Tipo] 
FROM [KLABIN_SGL].[dbo].[TB_CAMINHAO] CONSCM
Where  [CAM_DT_REGISTRO] between GETDATE()-1 and GETDATE()
and DATEPART(Hour, [CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) <= DATENAME(HOUR,SYSDATETIME())-1
Order By [CAM_PF], [CAM_CD];
```

O resultado desta tabela traz uma grande lista cfme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado esperado é uma consulta com a seguinte estrutura:

```
 CAM    Historico   Dados
 BBM013   20        50
 BBM017   15        45
```

Resumindo, estou tentando usar a consulta que montei em uma subquery, onde traga na query principal a contagem dos "DADOS" e "HISTORICO", eu realmente não consegui fazer a essa contagem de um campo calculado.

Alguém pode por gentileza me ajudar? dar umas dicas, exemplos?

Grato!

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o `GROUP BY` com a função `COUNT`:

```
SELECT CONSCM.CAM_PF AS CAM,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < LAG([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1) OVER (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] ORDER BY [CAM_CD] ASC)) OR ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < LAG([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],2) OVER (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] ORDER BY [CAM_CD] ASC)) THEN 1
               ELSE NULL) AS HISTORICOS,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < LAG([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1) OVER (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] ORDER BY [CAM_CD] ASC)) OR ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < LAG([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],2) OVER (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] ORDER BY [CAM_CD] ASC)) THEN NULL
               ELSE 0) AS DADOS
  FROM KLABIN_SGL.DBO.TB_CAMINHAO CONSCM
 GROUP BY CONSCM.CAM_PF
```

Comment: Olá, muiiiito obrigado pela dica tentei montar algo usando este exemplo , porém não tive sucesso, vou postar na resposta para ver @Sorack

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, tentei usar este exemplo, mas ainda estou com alguns problemas, 
Não consigo trazer os dados, dá este erro: 
"Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate."

Segue o SQL que estou usando:

```
SELECT CAM_PF AS CAM,

Sum(CASE WHEN 
([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < LAG([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1) OVER 
(PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] ORDER BY [CAM_CD] ASC))
THEN 1
ELSE NULL
end) AS HISTORICOS

FROM KLABIN_SGL.DBO.TB_CAMINHAO
GROUP BY CAM_PF,
[CAM_DT_REGISTRO],
[CAM_CD]
```

tem mais alguma dica de como proceder?

Como mencionei, eu preciso que conte quantos itens na condição abaixo:

```
([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < LAG([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1) OVER (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] ORDER BY [CAM_CD] ASC))
```

Trazendo o resultado por:

```
CAM_PF, [CAM_DT_REGISTRO], [CAM_CD]
```

Porém está dando erro no GroupBy,

Pode me dar uma ajuda?

Sds